# When does mapStateToProps occur in the component life cycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list of items in table. I want to be able to click on a `details` link on any item and go to a new page where I see the details of the item. Below is my code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import toastr from 'toastr';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as documentActions from '../../actions/documentActions';

class DocumentDetailsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.deleteDoc = this.deleteDoc.bind(this);
  }

  deleteDoc(id) {
    this.props.actions.deleteDocument(id)
      .then(res => toastr.success('Document deleted successfully!'));
  }

  render() {
    const { document } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="col s12">
        <div className="card qBox">
          <div className="card-content white-text">
            <span className="card-title">{document.title}</span>
            <p
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: document.content }}
            className="document-content"></p>
            <br />
            <p>Access Type: &nbsp;
              <span>{(document.access).toUpperCase()}</span></p><br />
            <div>
                Published Date :
              <p>{(document.createdAt) ?
                document.createdAt.split('T')[0] : ''}</p>
              <p id="owner">Author:
                {document.owner.firstName} {document.owner.lastName}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="card-action">
            <Link to="/">back</Link>
            {this.props.auth.user.userId === document.ownerId &&
              <div className="right">
                <Link to={`/document/${document.id}`}>Edit</Link>
                <Link to="/" onClick={this.deleteDoc()}> Delete </Link>
              </div>
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

DocumentDetailsPage.propTypes = {
  document: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  actions: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function getDocumentById(documents, id) {
  const document = documents.filter(item => item.id === id);
  if (document) return document[0];
  return null;
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const documentId = ownProps.params.id; // from the path `/document/:id`
  let document;

  if (documentId && state.documents.length > 0) {
    document = getDocumentById(state.documents, parseInt(documentId, 10));
  }

  return {
    document,
    auth: state.auth,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(documentActions, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DocumentDetailsPage);
```

When I click on the `details` link, it should take me to this page with route `document/:id` where I can read the `id` from the route and fetch the corresponding document from state and render in the component. But when i go to this page, it tells me that `document` is undefined. Any reason for this? or is there a better way to get the param `id` from the route than using `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: From what I'm seeing, you have the documentId passed in as normal props to the component, but the document passed in from the store. mapStateToProps only gets called when the _redux_ store gets updated, and might not get called when the props update (It's unclear to me whether this happens)

Regardless, it would seem to make sense that you would want to have the combined data in the redux store, or otherwise kick the redux store in order to trigger the mapStateToProps again.

Just a guess from reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

1) Your `deleteDoc` class method expects an `id` argument which is passed to your action creator. Because you already have the full document as a prop, get it from the object instead of receiving it:

```
 deleteDoc() {
    const { actions, document }  = this.props
    actions.deleteDocument(document.id)
      .then(res => toastr.success('Document deleted successfully!'));
  }
```

2) You're CALLING the `deleteDoc` function in your `onClick` handler!

```
// Wrong
<Link to="/" onClick={this.deleteDoc()}> Delete </Link>
```

Remove the parens and simply set a *reference* to your function as the `onClick` prop, not the result from an actual call. :)

```
// Right
<Link to="/" onClick={this.deleteDoc}> Delete </Link>
```